# Dell Inspiron 660 Hard Disk Drive Failure no harddrive connected

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios, sata

I've been looking around for a solution to this but haven't quite found anything that matches my scenario.

I have a Dell Inspiron 660. There are no drives connected. There are no SATA cables plugged in. The SATA drive is not on the Boot Priorty list. On boot, I get an error message: "Hard-disk Drive Failure. F1 to continue. F2 to enter setup."

I'm trying to boot from USB which is listed in the first spot in my boot priority, but I always get that error.

I've cleared the BIOS using the cmosclr pins and removed the CMOS battery for a few days just to be sure.

I've reached the conclusion that something is messed up in the BIOS or the motherboard itself. Does this conclusion sound accurate? Is there anything I should try before getting a new motherboard?

I'm pretty familiar with computer hardware and configuration, but figuring this out is a little beyond me.

Comment: Try updating ram it may work.

Answer (score 1):

If possible try to connect a working Hard disk to the motherboard, and then see whether you get the same error.

In case if you get the same error, there might be a problem with the motherboard.
If not, update the BIOS and carry on.

If you can't get a working hard disk, try a live CD, such as a Live version of Windows. With that, try to update your BIOS, and chances are, it might work. But nothing can be guaranteed.